# sbt test is slow, sbt test-only is fast

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm experiencing some perplexing behavior when running tests from SBT.  I have a project with ~100 ScalaTest tests.  They all ran in a few seconds.  I added a dozen more larger tests that take around a second each in IntelliJ.  When I run them in SBT via "test" they pass, but take on the order of 10 minutes.  When I run them in SBT via "test-only" they pass in seconds, similar to when I run them in IntelliJ.

I tried tinkering with the heap memory, the parallel test running settings, and forking, but nothing I've done fixes the problem.  Unfortunately it's not an open-source project, but any hypotheses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: load up jvisualvm, attach to the sbt process, enable snapshot tracking, `test`, stop snapshot tracking. Review hotspots, fix.